# Multidimensional van der Waerden, bounds for squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, ramsey-theory, arithmetic-progression

Given $r$, let $f(r)$ be the smallest $N$ such that for any $r$-coloring $C:\{1,\dots,N\}^2 \to \{1,\dots,r\}$, there exists $x,y,d\neq 0$ such that $C((x,y)) = C((x+d,y))= C((x,y+d))=C((x+d,y+d))$.

I know it is an open problem to get any "reasonable" bounds for the density analog to this question. But, I realized it may be open to even do this for colorings.

I am aware that the methods from David Conlon's paper "Monochromatic combinatorial lines of length three", should imply that $f(r)$ is upper bounded by a tower of two's of height $O(r)$. But this works for the more general Hales-Jewett numbers. Is a better result known for squares?

Comment: I'm sure anyone who can answer this question follows both co.combinatorics and nt.number-theory, but I've proposed adding the latter tag just in case.